# Meaning of <..> in Python inspection

Tags: python

In an IPython session, I have the following:

```
> my_array?
Type:       ndarray
String Form:
[[ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.] <...> [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]
           [ 1.]]
Length: 500
```

What does **`<...>`**  mean above? Do I have a 1D array of 1D arrays or something else?

Comment: This looks a little odd, presumably because of IPython, but my instinct is that it's a recursive structure that contains itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<...>` is simply how IPython skips over values when a string would otherwise be too long.  In [IPython/core/oinspect.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/oinspect.py):

```
    # String form, but snip if too long in ? form (full in ??)
    if detail_level >= self.str_detail_level:
        try:
            ostr = str(obj)
            str_head = 'string_form'
            if not detail_level and len(ostr)>string_max:
                ostr = ostr[:shalf] + ' <...> ' + ostr[-shalf:]
                ostr = ("\n" + " " * len(str_head.expandtabs())).\
                        join(q.strip() for q in ostr.split("\n"))
            out[str_head] = ostr
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks!  So in the example above. What is the shape of my array? Do I have a 1D array nested within another 1D array, or something else?

Comment: @user273158: looks to me like a 2D array of shape (500, 1): 500 rows, 1 column, not to be confused with a 1D array of shape (500,).  You can check it by printing `my_array.shape`.